# I can select a row when add space after character condition

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem. When I used 1 of 2 query :

```
select * from GMIS.dbo.TELLER_HIS WHERE ID = 'TT1821103235;1    'AND DR_CR_MARKER = 'DEBIT  '
select * from GMIS.dbo.TELLER_HIS WHERE ID = 'TT1821103235;1' AND DR_CR_MARKER = 'DEBIT'
```

I can add 1 or many space after condition, it only have 1 result.
ID, DR_CR_MARKER in result have not any one space.
please help!
 : 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you are asking, effectively, why `'abcdefg' = 'abcdefg    '` evaluates to TRUE? *(Your "question" is **very** unclear.)*

This is the way the SQL Server works with `(n)varchar` and `(n)char` datatypes. With a `(n)varchar` the value is "unpadded". Thus the value `'abcdefg    '` would be treated as `'abcdefg'`. Hence why `'abcdefg' = 'abcdefg    '` evaluates to TRUE.

For `(n)char`, the data is padded to the length of the data type. Let's, for example, take a `char(12)`: the values `'abcdefg'` and `'abcdefg    '` would both be treated as `'abcdefg      '`, and thus evaluate to TRUE as well.

Example:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CONVERT(varchar(20),'abcdefg') = CONVERT(varchar(20),'abcdefg    ') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
SELECT CASE WHEN CONVERT(char(20),'abcdefg') = CONVERT(char(20),'abcdefg    ') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

Both these statements return `1`;

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LTRIM & RTRIM](https://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-trim.html) Function in SQL Server

```
SELECT * 
FROM GMIS.dbo.TELLER_HIS 
WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(ID)) = 'TT1821103235;1' 
AND LTRIM(RTRIM(DR_CR_MARKER)) = 'DEBIT'
```

If You want to Differentiate between those Queries Use Like Operator

Without Spaces

```
SELECT * 
FROM GMIS.dbo.TELLER_HIS 
WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(ID)) = 'TT1821103235;1' 
AND LTRIM(RTRIM(DR_CR_MARKER)) like 'DEBIT'
```

With Spaces

```
SELECT * 
FROM GMIS.dbo.TELLER_HIS 
WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(ID)) = 'TT1821103235;1   ' 
AND LTRIM(RTRIM(DR_CR_MARKER)) like 'DEBIT    '
```

The Like Query with Space will give no data.